# integrate wordpress post in existing website

Tags: wordpress

I have this website i just completed and i want to integrate my existing wordpress with it.
Note on the homepage i want to pull posts from the wordpress database in and display it in short form as follows

image 
title
excerpt

Also i want the full post content to display in another page blog page.
i.e

fetch posts content from DB
display content

All i want to know is that is there a way to just fetch this posts content from the Database and use it as i want on my custom pages ?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but the best course of action would be to integrate your existing website into a WP theme.

Comment: how can that be done, am good with php

Comment: See answer below, to bring WordPress outside of Wordpress :} May need to adjust the path to `wp-load.php` based on your environment and where WP is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access WordPress outside of WordPress and execute a query like so:

```
<?php

    // Bring in WordPress
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Setup your query
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_status'=>'publish'
        // adjust as you need
    );

    // Execute your query
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        while( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            // Loop through resulting posts

            $posts->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumb-rectangle' );
            }

            // Now do something with your post
?>
<div class="pod">
<?php if( $thumbnail ) { ?><img src="<?php echo( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>" width="" height="" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><?php } ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php           
        }
    }
```

Quick modification to display one post:

```
<?php

    // Bring in WordPress
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Setup your query
    $args = array(
        'p' => __post_id_here__
        // adjust as you need
    );

    // Execute your query
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $posts->have_posts() ) {

            $posts->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumb-rectangle' );
            }

            // Now do something with your post
?>

<?php if( $thumbnail ) { ?><img src="<?php echo( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>" width="" height="" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><?php } ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php           
    }
```

Comment: But also i would like to display a particular post on a page (full).

Comment: what other functions can i use to obtain the date posted and the post id

Comment: `get_the_ID()` will grab the post ID, you can output it like: `echo ( get_the_ID() );`. You can use the WordPress date function `the_date( 'Y-m-d' );` changing `Y-m-d` will change the date format: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time